# Calculating a checksum of a real array in Fortran

Tags: hash, fortran, checksum

I have a large array in Fortran:

```
real, dimension(N) :: arr
```

And I need to check if the array is exactly the same in different runtimes of the program. To do this, I wanted to create a checksum of the array to compare. However, I don't know which algorithm to implement. I have looked at Flether's and Adler's algorithm, but have trouble reading the C syntax provided in the examples I found. And also, I don't know how to implement them with Reals instead of chars/integers.

In the C implementations I have found they return:

```
return (b << 16) | a;
```

But I don't know how to implement the `b << 16` part in Fortran, or if this translates well to reals.

Comment: So which checksum algorithim you want to implement? Did you do any research? Are you asking for the algorithm or you do not know how to implement in Fortran? I am afraid the question is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Not that much different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49943987/fibonacci-random-number-generator you are just lucky that less people to downvote are following the Fortran tag.

Comment: I don't understand how the question you linked to is similar to my question @VladimirF

Comment: In the spirit - no code, no algorithm, no details.

Comment: I have updated the question to provide more details. Please let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: I would recommend a focused question just about the bit you do not understand. You can then ask another focused question later. Stay away from questions that are too broad. It is possible to translate that code to Fortran, but we also have to know the size of `a` and `b`.

Comment: `b << 16` applies to integers and translates to `b * 65536`. Also `x | y` translates to `x .or. y`.

Comment: Is the premise here that `IF( a == b )` would be too slow?

Comment: It is IOR rather that `.or.`.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I don't write the array to a file. I want to write the checksum to the terminal so I can keep track of whether or not the checksum remains the same through different runs.
That's also why I can't just perform `all(a==b)` @ja72, since the arrays are not in the same runtime.

Comment: The problem in the other half of the question is answerable, but the question needs to be narrowed down to that, really.

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved the issue by implementing Adler-32 in Fortran:

```
subroutine test_hash(var)
  implicit none
  real, dimension(N), intent(in) :: var
  integer, dimension(N) :: int_var
  integer :: a=1, b=0, i=1, mod_adler=65521, hash = 0

  int_var = TRANSFER(var, a, nijk)

  do i= 1, NIJK
    a = MOD(a + int_var(i), mod_adler)
    b = MOD(b+a, mod_adler)
  end do

  hash = ior(b * 65536, a)

  print*, hash

end subroutine test_hash
```

I ended up using the Fortran intrinsic [Transfer](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/TRANSFER.html) function to convert the 32bit reals to 32bit integers, since that's what the algorithm relies on. After this I perform the standard loop. Use the [IOR](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/IOR.html) function as suggested by @VladimirF and represented the `b<<16` as `b * 65536` described by @ja72. 
Finally I'll be able to print the hash to the console.

The reason for implementing it this way was because it's faster in use than opening a file, computing the checksum per file. The main reason for this is because there are many variables I need to check which switch often since I'm only using this for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

A modified version of Lars accomplishes the same without a large temporary array. Also, in Fortran, initializing the variable at declaration time implies the "save" attribute, which is not desirable in this case.

```
    function hash_real_asz(var,size_var) result(hash)
      implicit none
      integer(8) :: hash
      real(8), dimension(*), intent(in) :: var
      integer, intent(in) :: size_var
      integer(4) :: a,b,i,j
      integer(4), parameter :: mod_adler = 65521
      integer(4), allocatable :: tmp(:)

      a = 1
      b = 0

      do i= 1, size_var
        tmp = transfer(var(i), [0]) ! tmp will be an integer array sufficient to hold var(i)
        do j = 1,size(tmp)
            a = MOD(a+tmp(j), mod_adler) 
            b = MOD(b+a, mod_adler)
        end do
      end do

      hash = ior(b * 65536, a)

    end function
```

Comment: On the other hand, using kind magic constants like 4 and 8 is not desirable either nor is it consistent with the question.